# Maven MOJO Execution Failed while Building

Tags: java, maven, mojo

I'm trying to run [OpenOLAT LMS Project](http://hg.openolat.org/openolat102/file/00480d4073f6) (an Open Source Learning Platform written in Java) from source

but I got the following maven error in netbeans output and I can't build the project.

```
Failed to execute goal org.openolat.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.2.0:hgchangeset (default) on project openolat-lms: Command failed.
EXECUTION FAILED
Execution of cmd : id failed with exit code: 127.
Working directory was:
/home/aboud/NetBeansProjects/openolat
Your Hg installation seems to be valid and complete.
Hg version: NA (OK)
-> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

and here's the full stack trace of errors when I run `mvn -e clean install`

```
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command failed.
EXECUTION FAILED
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: First use an uptodate version of the [buildnumber-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/) furthermore try such executions on command line and **NOT** within your IDE.

Comment: Actually, running mvn from command line outputs the same error.
I'm trying to run it as is, should I change buildnumber version in pom?

Comment: A full pom would be also helpful.

Comment: [pom.xml](http://hg.openolat.org/openolat102/file/00480d4073f6/pom.xml)

Comment: you can browse and download project files [here](http://hg.openolat.org/openolat102/file/00480d4073f6)

or full [gz](http://hg.openolat.org/openolat102/archive/00480d4073f6.tar.gz) archive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no problem with Maven version 3.1.1.

Note there is no need to run `mvn -e clean install`, we never do it like this. This will run all the testcases including the Selenium tests which need a test configuration in `src/test/java/olat.local.properties` and test database environment. Please read the `TESTING.README.LATEST` at the top level of the project to learn more about running the unit tests.

So, to get started quickly just run `mvn clean package` to build the war file or `mvn eclipse:eclipse` if you want to run OpenOLAT in eclipse for development.

Cheers Florian